# Use of next/prev for site navigation

Tags: html, hyperlink

Google gives me the impression that links of the type "link rel=next" are for use with multiple-part documents - where a doc is spread over several pages.  Do I break anything or go against accepted usage  if I put rel=next links on all of my site's pages so that it is easy to navigate through the site using a browser that supports these links (eg lynx)?  (In the early days of the web, hitting the space-bar when at the end of a page navigated to the "next" page, presumably according to a rel=next link.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the next link relation indicates that the links context is part of a series...so you are going against convention, but i'm not sure about breaking anything. if services are set up to consume your documents, and they use it, then totally. it may affect seo as well, if google figures out they're not in order, but that's must me speculating. you can read all about link relations here: http://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xml